# OP edits its question with solution, newbee comment on the solution, what do?

Tags: discussion

Here's the scenario:

- OP ask [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052112/cakephp-3-mercury-smtp-server-did-not-accept-the-password);
- OP finds the solution and edit its question with it;
- lambda user post an answer commenting on the solution.

In a sense the answer seems valid since it repeats it.

> I can't believe, but `...` is the solution. Why?

---

What should I do?

- Flag the answer as *This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question*;
- Remove edit from OP and answer the question by myself;
- Vote to close the whole question as *While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers*;
- ...?

Comment: The edit where the solution was added to the question should be rolled back and the answer that was posted isn't an really an answer since it is asking questions about it so handle that as you see fit.

Comment: Your post triggered massive downvote on that answer. OP has no idea what's happening :/

Comment: Fair warning to folks under 2K - attempting to rollback these kinds of edits  where OP either added the answer to the question or changed the question and invalided existing answers will get your edit rejected. Better to get assistance from someone who can make edits without needing approval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should obviously flag this as not an answer, and suggest that the OP answers his own question (with an answer, rather than a question edit) if he genuinely has found a solution and it is of use to others.