# How handle OP editing question with solution

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, self-answer

This in regards to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481437/python-shapely-how-to-determine-if-two-polygons-cross-each-other-while-allowi/38745732#38745732).

The OP found a solution and instead of posting as an answer, edited the question to show the solution.

I commented on the post hoping the OP would change his edit to an answer, but to no avail. What is the proper next step? Is it better to leave it as an edit or add it as my own answer?

For now I have posted the edit as an answer (community wiki so I don't benefit) and removed the edit from the question.

I have looked at this post, but it only recommends the comment, and not further steps:
[OP edits its question with solution, newbee comment on the solution, what do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314534/op-edits-its-question-with-solution-newbee-comment-on-the-solution-what-do)

Comment: What you did looks like it was the right thing to do (although it's pretty much a "code only" answer and could benefit from more context.)

Comment: Editing is one of the better ways to teach the newbies the site ropes.  Well, he's not a newbie, is not awol and that you have to support the answer for the rest of your natural life and get meta criticism does kinda suck.  You need to want to fix the problem, looks like you did, it's as good as it gets.

Comment: `in regards to this question` Isn't this supposed to be tagged with specific-question?

Comment: Next time, you can just click the "rollback" link from the previous edit instead of editing the question and removing by hand the added solution.

Comment: @LarsTech good point, for some reason I thought there had been other changes made in the previous edit besides this addition.

Comment: @dorukayhan the question is just an example, this post was more about the general case